# Override encoding

Tags: php, encoding, byte-order-mark

I have a php file that should echo nothing when everything is ok. But, due to hosting server setting (In my opinion) it echoes BOM.

Can I somehow override encoding for that file, so it echoes nothing, not even BOM?

(P.S. this was working for quite some time, it started to echo BOM without editing from my side).

Comment: It's not due to server settings but due to file contents. If your script outputs BOM - then you're a person to answer why you do that.

Comment: To clarify zerkms' comment: I can think of a few ways to dynamically inject a BOM into the web server's output so it's technically possible but it looks way more likely that you inadvertently changed your editor settings (or processed your files with some batch edit tool). Are you 100% sure that your files do not have a BOM?

Comment: I downloaded file from ftp, opened in notepad++, selected utf 8 encoding without bom, and it still have bom, and it's same size.

Comment: Any sugestions what editor to use, or other sugestions to avoid echoing bom? Thanks.